# The welcome module throws an error = ChatMemberUpdated' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, chatbot, group

Heroku Log's

```
Application Logs
app[worker.1]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'downloads/welcome#1378327818.png'

 app[worker.1]: 

app[worker.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

app[worker.1]: 
 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):

app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/dispatcher.py", line 240, in handler_worker

 app[worker.1]:     await handler.callback(self.client, *args)

app[worker.1]:   File "/app/NeonRobot/utils/errors.py", line 56, in capture

app[worker.1]:     message.text or message.caption,

app[worker.1]: AttributeError: 'ChatMemberUpdated' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Не знаю как решить проблему так как сам не разбираюсь в кодирование и языка программирования.
Учусь над готовым проектом.
добавля новый модули из других проектовü